# Take two arrays of strings and return an array with the combinations of the items in them

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to take two arrays and return a single array with the combination of the items in them, listing the first items first. Like so:

```
combinations(["on","in"],["to","rope"])
# => ["onto","onrope","into","inrope"]
```

I've written a method that does this, but after that, I can't figure out where to go.

Comment: What's expected output in uneven array sizes like : `combinations(["on","in"],["to","rope", "test"])`

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
["on","in"].product(["to","rope"]).map(&:join)
# => ["onto", "onrope", "into", "inrope"]
```

Comment: This is how I would do it.  It would be nice if you elaborated a bit what the array product method does. Probably just showing them as two separate steps would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
def combinations(ary1, ary2)
  ary1.map {|i| ary2.map {|i2|  "#{i}#{i2}" }}.flatten
end
```